# CSS not applied after executing AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I am struggling with an issue after an AJAX request. I am requesting data from the database. That itself works perfectly and I process the data and add it into a table within the PHP file. That table consists of a caption followed by the data. This table is then transferred to the main page where it is displayed. My problem is that I am trying to format the buttons that I create in the PHP to be formatted as well. Here's the PHP with the data request

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT LoginName FROM table";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

        echo "<center>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>User</td>";
        echo "<td colspan=2 align=center>Available Functions</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['User'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><button type='button' class='smallbutton'>Delete User</button></td>";
            echo "<td><button type='button' class='smallbutton'>Change Password</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</center>";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

As you can see I assigned a class to the buttons. I thought it was easy to use that as a formatting tag for CSS. My css file looks like the following:

```
.smallbutton {
font-size:16px;
padding: 10px 10px;
border: none;
background-color: #008CBA;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
color: white; }
```

Every time the code is executed, which is on the refresh of the page, the table is created but the buttons look like those ugly standard buttons and the CSS is not applied. I was able to include the style into the PHP file which then worked but that is really not how I want to structure my page. The PHPs are really only the data provider and I want to use CSS in a central location for the layouts.

I already use the same CSS just with another class name for other buttons and they, no matter where they are located on the page, work perfectly. Just these ones in that table I create, do not want to work.

The table is embedded in a div which has the ID "DbInfo" and is filled via innerHTLM.

Just in case here's also my AJAX command:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "UserData.php",
    success: function(data){
        $("#DbInfo").innerHTML = data;
    }
});  });
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks...

Comment: What happened when you use `$("#DbInfo").html( data );`?

Comment: where is your css located

Comment: does your browser console throw a 404 on your css style sheets?

Comment: Thanks guys for your feedbacks. I want to answer from top to bottom. When I use html(data) it is the same issue. The CSS is located in the same directory and called style.css. It is implented through the standard procedure <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">. No I do not get a 404 on my style sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just if someone is interested. I restructured my CSS and have explicit references. Instead of addressing only the class I added the button type as well. The new css looks like this:

```
button[type=button].abutton {
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    color: white;
}

button[type=button].smallbutton {
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    color: white;
}
```

That allows me to address the items properly. Thanks to all your answers and Eric, who deleted his answer, but brought me on the right track.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can add id to your button.
Eg:-

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='button'>Delete User</button></td>";
echo "<td><button type='button' class='button'>Change Password</button></td>";
```

And set the css class from client side after you set innerHTML in your AJAX.
Eg:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",

    url: "UserData.php",

    success: function(data){

        $("#DbInfo").innerHTML = data;

        $(".button").addClass("smallbutton");

    }

});  
});
```

NOTE:- It is a bad practice to get all HTML code from server side via AJAX. Try to get only the data from your server via AJAX and construct your HTML table in client side.

Eg;-
php code

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    return;
}

$sql = "SELECT LoginName FROM table";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       array_push($data, $row['User']);
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($data);
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "UserData.php",
    success: function(data){
        var userData = JSON.parse(data);
//contruct HTML table using jquery here
    }
});
```

Comment: Answer is edited. the issue here is if you directly set the innerHTML, browser will not scan your HTML content and apply style. You need to specify your styles somehow explicitly. Previously in my answer I added the class via id. Now in my answer I added css class via a different css class.

Comment: Sir I am also using ajax and the class I implement in ajax called function all are working fine...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma sorry I thought it is the issue. is this issue happening because of css class is not found?

Comment: But anyway it is a bad practice to get all HTML code from server side via AJAX. Get only the data from server via AJAX and construct HTML table in client side is the correct way right?

Comment: I don't know much about that... Sorry.

Comment: @Shan Krishnan you got an example? how about you use my problem and highlight how to best do that. That would help tremendously. Thanks. I also could not make your above example to work. I am afraid that Eric Groft could be right and something is overwriting my class in the CSS.

Comment: @user3176132 I have added example in my answer check it.

Comment: @Shan. Thanks but I was hoping for the code to create the table. I was also trying your code form the first example which did not work. The buttons did not have the class "smallbutton" after running the code. Anyway if you could specify constructing the table that would be appreciated. Thanks.