# CSS active not getting applied after all data was loaded using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm building a table and pagination nav loaded using Ajax.
Everything in the table, including the sorting and filtering works fine except for the active style selection after clicking on page 2 for example.

This is the nav:

```
<nav id="UsersTableNavigation">
    <div id="navButtons"></div>
    <ul id='totalResultsUL'
        class='pagination justify-content-center small' style='color: gray;'></ul>
</nav>
```

The Ajax call:

```
$
.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : ".......",
    datatype : 'json',
    dataContent : 'application/json',
    data : dataRequestObject,
    success : function(result) {

        $('#errorNoDataOnTable').hide();
        $('#usersTable tbody').empty();

        if (!result)
            console.log("resultado null");

        totalFiltered = result.totalElements;
        totalPages = result.totalPages;
        limit = result.numberOfElements;
        $.each(
                result.content,
                function(index, user) {

                    // table content code here

                });

        $('#UsersTableNavigation #navButtons').empty();
        $('#UsersTableNavigation #totalResultsUL')
                .text("( "
                       + result.totalElements
                       + " Results");
        if (result.totalPages > 1)
            createPaginatioDiv(result.totalPages,
                    result.totalElements);

    },
    error : function(e) {
        $('#usersTable').empty();
        $('#errorNoDataOnTable').show();
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    }
});
}
```

the create nav for the pagination function:

```
function createPaginatioDiv(numPagesToShow, totalElements) {

    var navPart = "<ul id='paginationsUL' class='pagination justify-content-center'>"
            + "<li id='previousPagination' class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='#' "
                    +"tabindex='-1'>Previous</a></li>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= numPagesToShow; i++)
        navPart += "<li id 'paginationLI' class='page-item'><a id='paginationA' class='page-link' href='#' data-page='"+i+"' >"
                + i + "</a></li>";

    navPart += "<li id='nextPagination' class='page-item'><a  class='page-link' href='#' >Next</a></li></ul>";

    $('#UsersTableNavigation #navButtons').append(navPart);
    $('a[data-page="1"]').parent().addClass('active'); 
}
```

This -> `$('a[data-page="1"]').parent().addClass('active');` works fine as it is the first time it loads... The 'active' is implemented.
After I press any other page I can't get the addClass to work as I'm not refreshing the page...

Here is the "on document ready" part:

```
$(document).on(
"click",'#UsersTableNavigation #navButtons ul li a',
function(e) {

if(!isNaN($(this).text())){
    pageToGo = $(this).text();
} 

if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'nextPagination') {
    pageToGo++;
}
if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'previousPagination') {
    pageToGo--;
}

if (pageToGo > 1 && pageToGo < totalFiltered) {
    $('#previousPagination')
        .removeClass('disabled');
    $('#nextPagination')
        .removeClass('disabled');
}
if (pageToGo == totalFiltered) {
    $('#nextPagination').addClass(
        'disabled');
    $('#previousPagination')
        .removeClass('disabled');
}
if (pageToGo == 1) {
    $('#previousPagination')
        .addClass('disabled');
    $('#nextPagination')
        .removeClass('disabled');
}


$('a[data-page='+pageToGo+']').parent().addClass('active'); 
//get data using ajax
```

I saw some references to this situation but none solved my issue most likely for being newb.

The weirdest thing is that if I run `$('a[data-page='+pageToGo+']').parent().addClass('active');` as `$('a[data-page='3']').parent().addClass('active');` (for example) on the console the item gets active as desired...

Any idea how can I fix this?
Thank you for your time,

Eunito.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be awesome!

Comment: CSS will be applied to the relevant elements regardless of any timing issues, so you can take AJAX completely out of this equation. The problem is definitely either with specificity, or your elements not actually receiving the relevant classes (due to the JavaScript). Are you sure the elements **actually** have the relevant classes applied to them? If you inspect the elements, do other rules overwrite the `.active()` class? What do your `.active` and `.page-item` selectors look like?

Comment: Shouldn't the behavior be the same in the console and "on call?"?

Comment: @Eunito Check this out. It might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544620/css-not-applied-after-executing-ajax-request